# Recovering ST3 files after iOS crash

Tags: ios, sublimetext3, macos-sierra, iterm2

I am editing a project in Sublime Text 3 that included several text files.

When trying to save a file, ST3 gave me an error that said "Operation not Permitted" with some other information I can't remember.

I closed and reopened ST3, as most of the files that were open had been previously saved from the past 2 days.

When I reopened sublime text there were no cached files, and several of my files were deleted.

I assume they were overwritten as empty by sublime text and then saved as such when I restarted the program.

I use iTerm2 which had also crashed, and still throwing the error:

`An error was encountered while creating a temporary file with mkstemps. Verify that /var/folders/09/bx70dwpj6xj2gzdcjh6clm240000gn/T/ exists and is writable.`

I assume these are related issues but don't know how to recover or restore the files this crash deleted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you recall using sudo at any point before the crash?

Would you be able to check how much free space you have on your hard drive?

Also, if you're on linux
https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1613

Comment: Yep, mine was because of free space. Thanks a lot Docker, you really deserve your `40G` of my root partition's space...according to someone I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Just today I encountered the same error with iTerm2, which lead me to this post. I was also having a lot of other problems with other software, mostly related to being unable to save things.

After much searching for issues with similar problems, I solved this by rebooting my computer, holding command-R during startup, running Disk Utility, and repairing disk permissions.

Notably, repairing disk permissions without restarting and going into recovery mode was NOT successful in resolving my problem. I just got a lot of "Invalid Argument" errors when it tried to repair permissions when I wasn't in recovery mode.

Hope this helps someone in the future that runs into this strange situation.

Comment: This worked for me and should be marked as correct answer

Comment: @DivinesLight Glad it helped you. Be aware though this only temporarily solved the issue. The actual root issue for me was a hardware problem: The internal hard drive cable on my MacBook was loose and that was causing the read/write errors that I was seeing. If your problems return, I would recommend investigating that angle next.